# AVPlayer playing radio stream multiple audios being played

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, avplayer

I am playing music radio stream in AVPlayer, i am using juke box library to play, the problem is
 1. Selecting radio station to play new view controller appears with radio channel detail, where you can pause and forward channels. The Radio starts playing. go back to list again select another radio channel, both channels start playing simultaneously, , and can it goes on
Below is the link of juke box

What i want to do is whenever one channel is being played and user selects another channel, stop channel one from playing

https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox

```
 fileprivate func invalidatePlayback(shouldResetIndex resetIndex: Bool = true) {
    stopProgressTimer()
    radioPlayer?.pause()
    radioPlayer?.rate = 0.0
    state = .paused
    radioPlayer = nil

    if resetIndex {
        playIndex = 0
    }
}

fileprivate func startNewPlayer(forItem item : AVPlayerItem) {
    invalidatePlayback(shouldResetIndex: false)
    radioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    radioPlayer?.allowsExternalPlayback = false
    radioPlayer?.rate = 1.0
    startProgressTimer()
    seek(toSecond: 0, shouldPlay: true)
    updateInfoCenter()
}
```

startNewPlayer is called whenever you select radio channel from list.
Anybody can help me with this?Please